# How do I databind to the control's property rather than the datacontext?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a sub control embedded inside my main control, it allows the user to edit an address.  Because this is reused all over the place (sometimes in multiple places on one control) I bind it like so

```
<Controls:EditAddressUserControl DataContext="{Binding Path=HomeAddress}"/>
<Controls:EditAddressUserControl DataContext="{Binding Path=WorkAddress}"/>
```

But the EditAddressUserControl needs access to the main control's list of CountrySummary objects so it can choose which country the address belongs to.

I have added a Countries DependencyProperty to EditAddressUserControl and added

```
Countries="{Binding Countries}"
```

So far all is going well, the EditAddressUserControl.Countries property has the correct countries in it.  However, how do I databind my Combobox.ItemsSource to that in XAML?

I still want everything on my EditAddressUserControl to bind to its DataContext, but the ComboBoxCountries.ItemsSource needs to bind to "this.Countries".

How do I do that?

I've tried this

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Controls:EditAddressUserControl}}, Path=Countries}" />
```

I saw no binding errors in the output box, but I also saw no items in the combobox.

Comment: Is the `EditAddressUserControl` the sub-control or the parent one? You should specify the parent one in the AncestorType

Comment: EditAddressUserControl is the embedded control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it was to stop using DataContext completely.  Instead I added a DependencyProperty to my control

```
public static DependencyProperty AddressProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Address", typeof(EditPostalAddressDto), typeof(EditPostalAddressControl));
```

Then in the parent control instead of setting DataContext="..." I set Address="..." - The XAML for the control is then changed to include an ElementName on the binding

```
<UserControl ..... x:Name="MainControl">
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=MainControl,Path=Address.Region}"/>
```

Now I can specifically bind to the Address property, but also bind to properties on the main data context.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using a [RelativeSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.aspx) for the binding source, instead of the DataContext.

This would most likely look something like:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Controls:EditAddressUserControl}}, Path=Countries}" />
```

Comment: This will work, provided you set it up correctly. You need to get the relative source to "find" the appropriate class in your ancestor hierarchy, where the DP is defined.  I guessed on the syntax based on what you placed.